# Updating state with form inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Made a mess out of this one. The app opens a list with products and each product has an edit button, where you can change the information through inputs and then save that information with save button. But the state doesn't update itself and currently I can't type anything into the input field. I've been messing with this for several hours and checked React forms tutorial, but I'm still missing something. I've already got a form, which creates and inserts the product to the list and I've tried to copy it for product editing, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance, if you can spot the problem.

App code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProductList from "../ProductList/ProductList";
import NewProd from "../NewProd/NewProd";
import ViewProd from "../ViewProd/ViewProd";
import EditProd from "../EditProd/EditProd";
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };
};

handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];
  products.push({
      name: this.state.name,
      ean: this.state.ean,
      type: this.state.type,
      weight: this.state.weight,
      color: this.state.color,
      active: false,
  });
  this.setState({ products, 
    name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: "", active: false}
  );
}
handleEditFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let products = [...this.state.products];
  products.splice(1, 1, {name: this.state.name,
    ean: this.state.ean,
    type: this.state.type,
    weight: this.state.weight,
    color: this.state.color,})
  this.setState({ products, name: "", ean: "", type: "", weight: "", color: ""}
  );
}

handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({...this.state,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  };

deleteProduct = (delIndex) => {
  let products = [...this.state.products].filter((product, index) => index !== delIndex);
  this.setState({ products });
};
isActive = () => {
  this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
}
setProductActive = (product, active) => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    products: state.products.map(p => p.name === product.name ? { ...p, active } : p)
  }))
}

render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <ProductList products={this.state.products} 
      deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct}
      setProductActive={this.setProductActive} />
      <NewProd handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
      handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
      newName={this.state.name}
      newEan={this.state.ean}
      newType={this.state.type}
      newWeight={this.state.weight}
      newColor={this.state.color} />
      <Route path="/view" render={(props) => <ViewProd {...props} products={this.state.products} />} />
      <Route path="/edit" render={(props) => <EditProd {...props} products={this.state.products} 
      handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
      handleEditFormSubmit={this.handleEditFormSubmit}
      handleFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
      editName={this.state.name}
      editEan={this.state.ean}
      editType={this.state.type}
      editWeight={this.state.weight}
      editColor={this.state.color} />} />
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Edit Prod code

```
import React from "react";
import "./EditProd.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class EditProd extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        const products = this.props.products;
        const index = this.props.location.state.prodIndex;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Edit Product</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.handleEditFormSubmit} >
            <label htmlFor="name">Product Name: </label>
            <input id="editname" type="text" name="name" placeholder={products[index].name} value={this.props.editName} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="ean">EAN Code: </label>
            <input id="editean" type="text" name="ean" placeholder={products[index].ean} value={this.props.editEan} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="type">Product Type: </label>
            <input id="edittype" type="text" name="type" placeholder={products[index].type} value={this.props.editType} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="weight">Product Weight: </label>
            <input id="editweight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder={products[index].weight} value={this.props.editWeight} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="color">Product Color: </label>
            <input id="editcolor" type="text" name="color" placeholder={products[index].color} value={this.props.editColor} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
            <Link to={{ pathname: "/"}} ><button>Close</button></Link>
        </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
export default EditProd;
```

Product List Code

```
import React from "react";
import "./ProductList.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        const products = this.props.products;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Product List</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>EAN Code</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Active</th>
                    </tr>
                    {products.map((product, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{product.name}</td>
                                <td>{product.ean}</td>
                                <td>{product.type}</td>
                                <td>{product.weight}</td>
                                <td>{product.color}</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" checked={product.active} onChange={(e) => this.props.setProductActive(product, e.target.checked)} /></td>
                                <td><Link to={{ pathname: "/view", state: { prodIndex: index }}} ><button>View</button></Link></td>
                                <td><Link to={{ pathname: "/edit", state: { prodIndex: index }}} ><button>Edit</button></Link></td>
                                <td><button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(index)}>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ProductList;
```

New Product code

```
import React from "react";

class NewProd extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleFormSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="name">Product Name: </label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value={this.props.newName} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="ean">EAN Code: </label>
            <input id="ean" type="text" name="ean" value={this.props.newEan} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="type">Product Type: </label>
            <input id="type" type="text" name="type" value={this.props.newType} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="weight">Product Weight: </label>
            <input id="weight" type="text" name="weight" value={this.props.newWeight} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <label htmlFor="color">Product Color: </label>
            <input id="color" type="text" name="color" value={this.props.newColor} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Add New Product</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default NewProd;
```

EDIT: As each product is an object in the array, would it be possible instead of updating the state, to remove the specific array object, based on the index, and replace it with the updated inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is your using the `name` of the input to set the state variable but the names of the state variables are completely different from those in the inputs.There are no state variables called `editName`,`editEan`,`editType`,`editWeight`,`editColor`  so you want to change that firstly

```
  <form onSubmit={this.props.handleEditFormSubmit}>
    <label htmlFor="name">Product Name: </label>
    <input id="editname" type="text" name="name" placeholder={products[index].name} value={this.props.editName} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
    <label htmlFor="ean">EAN Code: </label>
    <input id="editean" type="text" name="ean" placeholder={products[index].ean} value={this.props.editEan} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
    <label htmlFor="type">Product Type: </label>
    <input id="edittype" type="text" name="type" placeholder={products[index].type} value={this.props.editType} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
    <label htmlFor="weight">Product Weight: </label>
    <input id="editweight" type="text" name="weight" placeholder={products[index].weight} value={this.props.editWeight} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
    <label htmlFor="color">Product Color: </label>
    <input id="editcolor" type="text" name="color" placeholder={products[index].color} value={this.props.editColor} onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
    <Link to={{ pathname: "/"}} ><button>Close</button></Link>
</form>
```

Secondly you need to spread the state before setting a single item in the state

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({...this.state,
     [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  };
```

Comment: Yup, that answers one part of the problem, thank you very much. Now the inputs in Edit Product produce props. Now the problem is setting the state using the save button and updating it with the new edit props.

Comment: i'm a little confused what you're trying to do here.  Setting the input onChange should be enough to set the state

Comment: Let's say there is a list of products, each with its own name, ean, etc. Each product also has an edit button, which you press to edit the name, ean, etc. I need that the changes would be saved after pressing the save button and the list would be updated with the new inputs.

Comment: Okay i get it , i'll take a look at it again but it would help if you could provide a working example in codesandbox or something because i think it would be better to add state for the product rather than saving the values in an array

Comment: Appreciated. I've put the whole thing here. Replacing the array object instead of updating it worked, the only obstacle left is to specify the index so that a specific array object would be taken out. Need to pass the index from Edit Product component, to handleEditFormSubmit function. When I try to pass index as second argument next to event, the function breaks.

Comment: I've got it. Passing index as argument worked with proper syntax. Thank you for the help.